# want to print the in console as an output

Tags: perl

This is my sample code I want to print the report in the console as an output, I tried too many times but I unable to do this, new learner.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

# for loop execution
$b=0;
for( $a = 0; $a < 5; $a = $a + 1 ) {

   print "Enter your name please" ;
   my $name = <STDIN>;
   chomp $name;
   open(my $name, '>', 'report.txt');
   close $name;

}
```

Comment: Q: If you want to print to the console, then why are you redirecting to 'report.txt'???  Q: Does "report.txt" look OK?  Does it contain what you expect in the report?

Comment: Do you want to read some data in console and store it in a file?

Comment: Or you want to read content of the file and print it in the console?

Comment: If you want to read file and show it's content in the console then why not to use `more`, `less` or `cat`? [I assume that you use Linux/Unix OS]

Comment: @Polar Bear, You're assuming that's the only thing the program does rather than just the part with which the OP needs help.

Comment: @ikegami -- Judging by code OP wants to read from `STDIN` and output to `report.txt`. Then your answer is not correct because you read file and output it to the screen.

Comment: @Polar Bear, I answered the question asked, but it's entirely possible it's not what the OP actually wants. If they edit their question such that my answer is no longer relevant, I'll delete it. Until then, there are 4 or 5 possible things the OP might want, and I'm not going to post an answer for each of them. In short, I figured I'd get the ball rolling.

Comment: You do not see that file is open for **output**! And that input **collected** from `STDIN`.

Comment: You question is not clear -- one possibility is that you want to redirect output in the terminal to a file **report.txt**. Well then you should run a command as following `command | tee report.txt` -- you still will see output in the terminal and at the same time it will be redirected into **report.txt**. If you want to do same with a perl script then read from `STDIN`, print into terminal and print into the file.

Comment: Considering this is [an exact copy-paste of the OP's previous question, which was closed as unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59592070/3122701), I don't think this should have been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by provided piece of code you read from `STDIN` and output to **report.txt** file

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $report = 'report.txt';
my $a = 5;

open(my $fh, '>', $report)
    or die "Couldn't open $report";

while( $a-- ){
    print "Enter your name please: " ;
    my $name = <STDIN>;
    chomp $name;

    say $fh $name;

}

close $fh;
```

NOTE: your script includes `shebang` what indicates that you use Linux/UNIX

Answer (score 2):

```
my $qfn = 'report.txt';

open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

while (<$fh>) {
   print;
}
```

The last three lines are equivalent to

```
while ($_ = <$fh>) {
   print($_);
}
```

So you could also use

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
   print($line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is asking to print the console output into the report.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
# for loop execution
```

`$b=0; Now this is unwanted scalar variable declaration`

```
   for( $a = 0; $a < 5; $a = $a + 1 ) { # You can use $a++ here instead of $a = $a + 1 ;
   print "Enter your name please" ;
   my $name = <STDIN>;
   chomp $name; #You will check the filehandling I/O.
   open($filename, '>>', 'report.txt'); #You need to append the values into the report
   print $filename "$name\n";
   close $filename;
}
```

Just try this.

Comment: Keeping `>` but moving the `open` out of the loop makes more sense.

Comment: Absolutely, you are correct champ. I Just copied the OP's code and updated.

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to the case if OP wants to implement in perl feature provided by `tee` Linux/UNIX command. Man page [tee](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html).

Prior usage of the script it should be made executable `chmod +x script.pl`.

The command will continue to print into the terminal and save same output into file with provided **filename** or otherwise default file **report.txt**.

USAGE: `command | script.pl [filename]`

NOTE: old file gets overwritten

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $report = shift || 'report.txt';

open(my $fh, '>', $report)
    or die "Couldn't open $report";

while( <> ){
    say;
    say $fh $_;
}

close $fh;
```